# Unable to get data from backbone.js form to Spring MVC model using @RequestMapping

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, backbone.js, model

I'm using backbone.js as the view for Spring MVC app. I need to get signup form data from backbone form to the model in Spring MVC. I'm using @PostMapping("/register") in controller of Spring.

Previously I was using JSP's form tag which calls the getters and setters methods of the respective model on GET and POST. But how can I do similar thing in Backbone.js. I found no good documentation for the same.

//Code of controller class

```
@GetMapping("/register")
public ModelAndView showRegistrationForm(HttpServletRequest request){
    User user=new User();
    ModelAndView mv=new ModelAndView("reg-form");
    mv.addObject("user", user);
    return mv;
}

@PostMapping("/register")
public ModelAndView registerNewUser(
        HttpServletRequest request,
        @Valid @ModelAttribute("user") User userParam,
        BindingResult bindingResult,
        HttpServletResponse response){
    if(bindingResult.hasErrors()){
        System.out.println("The form has errors!!!!");
        return new ModelAndView("reg-form");
    }
```

I am trying to get user signup details and create a user entity in Spring.
I am new to Backbone.js, so please explain in detail how to do so.

Comment: I think you replaced two things that are not interchangeable. JSP is a templating engine that can work with Spring MVC directly but you might need to expose your data with a RestController as JSON to work with backbone.js.

Comment: Yes, I understand that, but how can I consume JSON data in my @RequestMapping method? Backbone is sending data to spring controller and the entity is also being created in database, but how can I show data in the view?

Comment: If you annotate the method with `RequestBody` and return the entity object instead of `ModelAndView` Spring should convert the entity on the fly. If possible annotate the whole controller with `@RestController` instead of `@Controller`.